# How inherits from lazy instantiation object?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

In my JavaScript code I have a lazy instantiation object AAA. I want make new object BBB and inherits from AAA.

How it's make?

Comment: You have to provide more information and a code example. Help us to help you!

Comment: Can't help without a lot more specific information, a code example of what you're trying to do and what you're doing with lazy instantiation.  Otherwise the question will get closed as it's unaswerable as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

standard javascript inheritance may be achieved with prototypes

```
BBB.prototype = new AAA();
```

But in this way you can not access parent methods if they are overridden. For this reason I'm using static property superclass e.g.

```
function AAA() {}
AAA.prototype = {
foo: function() {return 'foo';}
}

function BBB() {}
BBB.superclass = AAA.prototype;
BBB.prototype = {
foo: function() { return BBB.superclass.foo() + "bar";}
}
b = new BBB();
b.foo() //returns foobar
```

Comment: The parent's methods are always available via `AAA.prototype`, no matter which of the two ways above you choose.

Comment: yes but it's hard to maintain. If i change parent for some reason I have to make changes in all the functions that call parent while with static property change is made once.

Comment: You can still do `BBB.superclass =  AAA.prototype;`, even if you have `BBB.prototype = new AAA();`. Notice that your second way is actually no inheritance. What if `AAA.prototype` implements a method which gets not overridden? You can't do `b.bar()`. Or maybe I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes you are right about inheritance. In code above I've missed to copy AAA.prototype to BBB. My bad. My point was to share a way to access parent methods.

Answer (score 0):

I like to cheat, this will create objects inheriting from a common `o`.  I took the liberty of renaming variables you asked in your question.

```
var o = {
    happy: true,
    fun: true,
    time: true
}

var AAA = {
    happy: false
};
AAA.__proto__ = o;

console.log( 'happy', AAA.happy );
console.log( 'fun', AAA.fun );
```

Comment: `__proto__` is likely to be made non-writable in the nearish future.

Comment: Yeah thats why I called it a cheat.  Otherwise, you need to use `new` or god awful syntax of `Object.create`